# Conjugates of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

This is from a textbook:

> $w=i\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ where $z$ is also a complex number

Then

> $$\mathrm{Im}(w)=\frac{w-\bar w}{2i}$$

Then

> $$\mathrm{Im}(w)=\frac 1 {2i} \left(i\frac{1-z}{1+z}+i\frac{1-\bar z}{1+\bar z}\right)$$

The last part is that part I don't understand. I have looked at several identities and I can't figure out why

$$-\bar w =  i\frac{1-\bar z}{1+\bar z}$$

If someone could explain this to me I would appreciate it

Comment: What do you know about complex conjugation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply because conjugation is a field homomorphism: if $w=\mathrm i\dfrac{1-z}{1+z}$, then
$$\overline{w}=-\mathrm i\Bigl(\overline{\frac{1-z}{1+z}}\Bigr)=-\mathrm i\frac{\overline{1-z}}{\overline{1+z}}=-\mathrm i\frac{1-\bar z}{1+\bar z}.$$

Comment: That is,  $\bar A+ \bar B=\overline {A+B}$ and $\bar A \bar B=\overline {A B}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\bar w = \bar{i}\frac{1-\bar z}{1+\bar z}$$

Note that $\bar{i}=-i$. So you get:

$$-\bar w = i\frac{1-\bar z}{1+\bar z}$$

Answer (score 1):

The complex conjugate distributes through addition and multiplication, so $\overline{(z+w)} = \bar z+\bar w$ and $\overline{(zw)} = \bar z\bar w$. Division is just multiplication by the reciprocal, and the conjugate distributes through that too, so $\overline{(z/w)} = \bar z/\bar w$. Finally, the distinctive property of the conjugate is that it maintains the real part while it flips the sign of the imaginary part, so that $\bar 1 = 1$ and $\bar i = -i$. Put all of these rules together and you can see why the relation you are wondering about must be true.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand it in the following way:
$$w=\frac{a+b z}{c+dz}=\frac{(a+b z)(c^*+d^* z^*)}{(c+dz)(c^*+d^* z^*)}$$ The Denominator is a real number thus
$$
w^* = \frac{(a^*+ b^*  z^*)(c+d z)}{(c+dz)(c^*+d^* z^*)}=\frac{(a^*+ b^*  z^*)}{c^*+d^* z^*}
$$
I use the following identity if $z_1$ and $z_2$ are complex number
$(z_1 z_2)^*=z_1^* z_2^*$ and
$z_1^*$ is a complex conjugate number.

Answer (score 0):

We will use the following two theorems.

> **Theorem 1**:
>   The complex conjugate of the sum (difference) of two complex numbers is the sum (difference) of the complex conjugates.

**Proof**:
To show this, let $z_1=x_1+y_1$ and $z_2=x_2+y_2$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
\overline{\left(z_1\pm z_2\right)}&=\overline{(x_1\pm x_2)+i(y_1\pm y_2)}\\\\
&=(x_1\pm x_2)- i(y_1\pm y_2)=(x_1-iy_1)\pm (x_2-iy_2)\\\\
&=\overline{z_1}\pm \overline{z_2}
\end{align}$$

---

> **Theorem 2**:
>   The complex conjugate of the product (quotient) of two complex numbers is the product (quotient) of the complex conjugates.

**Proof**:
To show this for the product, we again let $z_1=x_1+y_1$ and $z_2=x_2+y_2$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
\overline{z_1z_2}&=\overline{(x_1+iy_1)(x_2+iy_2)}\\\\
&=\overline{(x_1x_2-y_1y_2)+i(x_1y_2+x_2y_1)}\\\\
&=(x_1x_2-y_1y_2)-i(x_1y_2+x_2y_1)\\\\
&=(x_1-iy_1)(x_2-iy_2)\\\\
&(\bar z_1)(\bar z_2)
\end{align}$$

**Proof**:
To show this for the quotient, we again let $z_1=x_1+y_1$ and $z_2=x_2+y_2$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
\overline{z_1/z_2}&=\overline{(x_1+iy_1)/(x_2+iy_2)}\\\\
&=\overline{\frac{(x_1+iy_1)(x_2-iy_2)}{|z_2|^2}}\\\\
&=\overline{\frac{(x_1x_2+y_1y_2)-i(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)}{|z_2|^2}}\\\\
&=\frac{(x_1x_2+y_1y_2)+i(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)}{|z_2|^2}\\\\
&=\frac{(x_1-iy_1)(x_2+iy_2)}{|z_2|^2}\\\\
&=\frac{x_1-iy_1}{x_2-iy_2}\\\\
&=(\bar z_1)/(\bar z_2)
\end{align}$$

---

Now, for the problem of interest, we have

$$w=i\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)$$

Thus, the complex conjugate of $w$ is

$$\begin{align}
\bar w &=\overline{i\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)} \tag 1 \\\\
&=-i\overline{\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)} \tag 2 \\\\
&=-i\frac{\overline{1-z}}{\overline{1+z}} \tag 3 \\\\
&=-i\frac{1-\bar z}{1+\bar z}\tag 4
\end{align}$$

where in going from $(1)$ to $(2)$ we used the Theorem 2 for the product rule, in going $(2)$ to $(3)$ we used Theorem 2 for the quotient rule, and in going from $(3)$ to $(4)$ we used Theorem 1 for both the sum and the difference.

And we are done!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.  - Mark